# Generate rays from origin in python

Tags: python, geometry, line, raycasting

I am trying to generate rays originating from origin (0,0) of certain length in all directions. I want these rays to be of a certain length. The rays should be cast in a 360 manner with a given resolution.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  
fig = plt.figure()


ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
a=0
b=10
for i in range(0,100):
    ax.add_line(Line2D([0,a], [0,b], linewidth=1, linestyle = "-", color="green"))
    a+=0.5
    b-=0.5
```

I have tried a naive approach as given above but neither can I get the 360 degree lines nor  control the resolution.

Comment: Hint: You actually want to produce lines at different angles. Use trigonometric functions (sin/cos) to convert from angle/radius to cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that is inspired by the answer given here: [Plotting a line from a coordinate with and angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417604/plotting-a-line-from-a-coordinate-with-and-angle)

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

#define origin and length
x, y = (0,0)
length=10

#iterate through possible angles and plot
for angle in range(0, 360, 1):
    # find the end point
    endy = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    endx = length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))

    ax.plot([x, endx], [y, endy])
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [turtle library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mode)
It has many different methods which you can play around with.

Following is a snippet that achieves what you are trying to do:

```
from turtle import *

# Color of the line segments drawn
color('red')

# Speed at which turtle draws
speed(100)

# Start drawing on the canvas until you come back to the origin
begin_fill()
while True:
    # Length of the line segment
    back(200)
    left(1)
    forward(200)
    print(position())
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break

# Finish drawing
end_fill()
done()
```

Comment: It does do what I am looking for but I need the coordinates for the lines as well. Otherwise its of no use.

Comment: You can use the position() method available in turtle. It returns the current position at which turtle is. I've edited my answer accordingly.